# Serialize nested objects and arrays to querystring

Tags: c#

I need to convert objects (potentially nested) and collections (`int[]`, `IEnumerable`s, `object[]`) into a query string that I can pass to a `GET` `HTTP` call.

I didn't find any complete answer on SO so I had to merge some answers and add something to make them all work together.

This is the current version that works with all the aforementioned data structures.

Performance shouldn't be a big issue as this has to work with relatively small objects anyway, but at the current state it's hard to read and I'm sure there are better ways to do that... that I cannot find myself.

```cs
        public static string ToQueryString(this object obj, string prefix = "")
        {
            bool IsDefaultType(Type type) => type.IsPrimitive || type == typeof(string) || type == typeof(DateTime);

            var properties = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            var queryString = new List<string>();

            if (typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(obj.GetType()) && obj.GetType() != typeof(string))
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(prefix))
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("You should not serialize an array without a prefix");
                }

                var enumerator = ((IEnumerable)obj).GetEnumerator();
                int i = 0;
                while (enumerator.MoveNext())
                {
                    properties.Add(i.ToString(), enumerator.Current);
                    i++;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                properties = obj.GetType().GetProperties()
                                    .Where(x => x.CanRead && x.GetValue(obj, null) != null)
                                    .ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x.GetValue(obj, null));

                if (properties.Count == 0 && IsDefaultType(obj.GetType()))
                {
                    properties.Add(prefix, obj);
                }
            }

            foreach (var prop in properties.Where(kv => kv.Value != null))
            {
                string key = string.IsNullOrEmpty(prefix) ? prop.Key : $"{prefix}[{prop.Key}]";
                var value = prop.Value;

                var valueType = value.GetType();
                if (IsDefaultType(valueType))
                {
                    if (valueType == typeof(DateTime))
                    {
                        value = ((DateTime)value).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss");
                    }
                    queryString.Add(key + "=" + value.ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    queryString.Add(value.ToQueryString(key));
                }
            }

            return string.Join("&", queryString);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `ToQueryString` implementation has clearly three separate parts:

- Get properties of an object
- Get members of a collection
- Format key value pairs

#### Get properties of an object

```cs
private static bool IsDefaultType(object @object)
    => @object.GetType().IsPrimitive || @object is string || @object is DateTime;

public static string ToQueryString(this object @object, string prefix = "")
{
    if (IsDefaultType(@object))
        return FormatDictionary(new() { { prefix, @object } }, prefix);

    var properties = @object.GetType().GetProperties()
                        .Where(x => x.CanRead && x.GetValue(@object, null) != null)
                        .ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x.GetValue(@object, null));

    return FormatDictionary(properties, prefix);
}
```

- I've made your `IsDefaultType` method `private static`

  - I've changed the type check to utilize [is operator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/is)
- I've moved the type check of the `ToQueryString` to the very first statement
- The `new () { { ... } }` creates a new `Dictionary<string, object>` with a single element

  - It relies on the [target type new expression](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/target-typed-new) (`new ()`), [collection initializer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers#collection-initializers) (`Dictionary)` and [object initializer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers#object-initializers) (`KeyValuePair`) features of C#

#### Get members of a collection

```cs
public static string ToQueryString(this IEnumerable collection, string prefix = "")
{
    if (collection is string)
        return ToQueryString((object)collection, prefix);

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(prefix))
        throw new InvalidOperationException("You should not serialize an array without a prefix");

    var members = collection
                .Cast<object>()
                .Select((value, idx) => new KeyValuePair<string, object>(idx.ToString(), value))
                .ToDictionary(item => item.Key, item => item.Value);
            
    return FormatDictionary(members, prefix);
}
```

- I've created another overload which accepts `IEnumerable`

  - If the extension method is called on a `string` then I'm delegating the handling to the previous method
  - Please note that explicit cast to `object`

    - If you forgot that then you will have an infinite recursion
- I've replaced your while loop with a Linq query

  - The non-generic `IEnumerable` does not have `Select` extension method that's why I had to call `Cast<object>` first
  - Then I've used the `Select` to get the [value and the index of the enumerable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43021/how-do-you-get-the-index-of-the-current-iteration-of-a-foreach-loop)
  - Finally I've used the `ToDictionary` to convert the `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>>` to the desired type

#### Format key value pairs

```cs
private static string FormatDictionary(Dictionary<string, object> properties, string prefix)
{
    var keyValues = new List<string>();
    foreach (var prop in properties.Where(kv => kv.Value != null))
    {
        string key = string.IsNullOrEmpty(prefix) ? prop.Key : $"{prefix}[{prop.Key}]";
        var value = prop.Value;

        if (IsDefaultType(value))
        {
            if (value is DateTime date)
                value = date.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss");
                    
            keyValues.Add(key + "=" + value.ToString());
        }
        else
            keyValues.Add(value.ToQueryString(key));
    }

    return string.Join("&", keyValues);
}
```

- I've get rid of the `valueType` variable and used the [is operator with declaration pattern](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/is)

---

I've tested the implementation with these test cases:

```
Hashtable table = new Hashtable();
table.Add("1", "1");
table.Add(2, DateTime.UtcNow);
Console.WriteLine(table.ToQueryString("table"));

List<int> list = new List<int>();
list.Add(1);
list.Add(10);
Console.WriteLine(list.ToQueryString("list"));

Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dict.Add("1", "1");
dict.Add("2", DateTime.UtcNow.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(dict.ToQueryString("dict"));

Console.WriteLine(DateTime.UtcNow.ToQueryString("date"));

Console.WriteLine("hello world".ToQueryString("string"));
```

the output was the following:

```
table[0][Key]=2&table[0][Value]=2021-11-03T13:37:47&table[1][Key]=1&table[1][Value]=1

list[0]=1&list[1]=10

dict[0][Key]=1&dict[0][Value]=1&dict[1][Key]=2&dict[1][Value]=11/3/2021 1:37:47 PM

date[date]=2021-11-03T13:37:47

string[string]=hello world
```

Comment: Great solution! This is the only implementation I could find in C# that uses brackets and not dots to separate entities from properties in the string, just like PHP does. Took me a day to find it, and works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you split the function into two parts. The first simply deals with formatting a single object and making it safe for the query string:

```
private static string FormatValue(object obj)
{
    string value;
    if (obj.GetType() == typeof(DateTime))
        value = ((DateTime)obj).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss");
    else
        value = obj.ToString();
    return HttpUtility.UrlEncode(value);
}
```

With this in place, you can simplify `ToQueryString` to the following:

```
public static string ToQueryString(this object obj, string prefix = "", int level = 0)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(prefix))
        throw new InvalidOperationException("You should not serialize without a prefix");
    if (typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(obj.GetType()) && obj.GetType() != typeof(string))
    {
        var items = (IEnumerable)obj;
        var index = 0;
        string queryString = "";
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            if (queryString != "")
                queryString += "&";
            queryString += item.ToQueryString(String.Format("{0}[{1}]", prefix, index++), level + 1);
        }
        return queryString;
    }
    else
    {
        return String.Format("{0}={1}", prefix, FormatValue(obj));
    }
}
```